# Calculate z-score given probability using erfinv

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$We know that the probability for a standard normal distribution may be calculated from:

$$p = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \erf\left(\frac z {\sqrt2}\right)\right)$$

Solving for $z$:

$$\erf\left(\frac z {\sqrt2} \right)  = 2p -1 $$

$$\frac z {\sqrt2}  = \erf^{-1}(2p -1) $$

$$z = \sqrt2 \erf^{-1}(2p - 1)$$ or
$$z = \sqrt2 \operatorname{erfinv}(2p-1)$$

For example, given $p = 0.001$, the correct answer is $-3.090232306$ but the above formula yields $-3.070852543$.  That is a $-0.63\%$ error.

The error is greater for small $p$, such as $p=0.001$ than for $p=0.999$ in which case, the correct answer is $3.090232306$ but the above formula yields $3.090232301$.  In this case the error is only $-0.00000017\%$.

**QUESTION**: why does this give  a different result than Excel and every z-score/probability calculator out there?
How do I fix this?  What is a good algorithm to calculate the z-score from the probability?

Comment: I don´t know which error do you mean. But the result which is calculated with Wolfram alpha does not differ significantly from the result you mentioned. [See here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(2)*erf%5E(-1)(0.002-1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method to compute $z$ is unstable. You suffer from catastrophic cancellation if you compute $2p-1$:

I do not know your algorithm, but let's assume that you are using an correctly rounded double precision function $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$. Now let  $p$ be smaller than
half of the machine epsilon ($\approx  2.2 \cdot 10^{-16}$ for IEEE double),
 then $2p-1=-1$ and all precision is lost. For larger $p$ you are loosing 'only' some precision.

A solution is to use the inverse of $\mathrm{erfc}$

$$p = \frac{1}{2}\biggl(1 + \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac {z}{\sqrt2}\right)\biggr)
= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left(-\frac {z}{\sqrt2}\right)$$

This follows from the facts that $\mathrm{erfc}(x)=1-\mathrm{erf}(x)$ and
$\mathrm{erf}(-x) = -\mathrm{erf}(x).$ 
Now solve for $z$:

$$z = -\sqrt{2} \; \mathrm{erfc}^{-1}(2p)$$

For a C++ implementation of erfc_inv see e.g. the 
[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) file erf_inv.hpp. My Pascal double routines give the following values:

```
    p             z with erf_inv          z with erfc_inv
 1.000E-03     -3.0902323061678136     -3.0902323061678136
 1.000E-04     -3.7190164854557088     -3.7190164854556809
 1.000E-05     -4.2648907939226017     -4.2648907939228247
 1.000E-06     -4.7534243088283059     -4.7534243088228987
 1.000E-07     -5.1993375821874714     -5.1993375821928174
 1.000E-08     -5.6120012442658487     -5.6120012441747891
 1.000E-09     -5.9978070105847330     -5.9978070150076874
 1.000E-10     -6.3613408896974226     -6.3613409024040566
 1.000E-11     -6.7060231434147486     -6.7060231554951368
 1.000E-12     -7.0344869100478356     -7.0344838253011313
 1.000E-13     -7.3488287482023118     -7.3487961028006774
 1.000E-14     -7.6507309051556440     -7.6506280929352704
 1.000E-15     -7.9414444874159802     -7.9413453261709970
 1.000E-16     -8.2095361516013874     -8.2220822161304366
 1.000E-17                     Nan     -8.4937932241095986
 1.000E-18                     Nan     -8.7572903487823162
```

$$ $$
**Edit** regarding algorithms: As already noted, there is
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_erf/error_inv.html which uses seven rational approximations.

The GSL routines
gsl_cdf_gaussian_Pinv, gsl_cdf_gaussian_Qinv from 
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/randist.html#the-gaussian-distribution
use the method from M. J. Wichura, “Algorithm AS 241: the percentage points of the normal distribution,” Applied Statistics, vol. 37, no. 3, pp. 477–484, 1988.

The Cephes library function [ndtri](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/doubldoc.html#ndtri)
computes for small $p$ an expansion in $\sqrt{-2 \ln p}$.

An asymptotic expansion of erfc⁡_inv for small arguments is given at
http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.17#iii.

The above results are from my Pascal port of the Boost routines.

Comment: That loss of precision is it - thank you!
$\mathrm{erfc}^{-1}$ is what I started out doing, but since it is not built in to Swift, I tried with just $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$.  
Do you know a good algorithm to compute $\mathrm{erfc}^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I added some algorithm URLs

Comment: Since accuracy is adequate for my purposes when $p > 0.5$, it occurs to me, a simpler way to deal with this might be to use just use $z = -\sqrt2 \;\; erfinv(2(1-p)-1) =   -\sqrt2 \;\; erfinv(1-2p)$ if $p>0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

We can confirm error is due to catastrophic cancellation of $2p-1$, by add back correction.

$y = \mathrm{erf}(x)\qquad\qquad\qquad → x = \mathrm{erf^{-1}}(y)$

$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\; \exp(-x^2)\quad\; → \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\; \exp((\mathrm{erf^{-1}}(y))^{\,2})$

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dp}\mathrm{cdf^{-1}}(p) = \frac{d}{dp} \sqrt2·\mathrm{erf^{-1}}(2p-1) = \sqrt{2\pi}\; \exp((\mathrm{erf^{-1}}(2p-1))^{\,2})$

Taylor series:
$\displaystyle \mathrm{cdf^{-1}}(p+h)\;=\;\mathrm{cdf^{-1}}(p)\;+\;\sqrt{2\pi}\; \exp(\frac{(\mathrm{cdf^{-1}}(p))^{\,2}}{2}) · h\;+\;O(h^2)$

Example, try $p=10^{-10}$

```
lua> p = 1e-10
lua> x = 2*p-1
lua> badp = (x+1)/2
lua> badz = icdf(badp)
lua> badp, badz
1.000000082740371e-010  -6.361340889697421

lua> h = p - badp
lua> badz + sqrt(2*pi) * exp(badz^2/2) * h
-6.361340902404055
lua> icdf(p)
-6.361340902404055
```